# Append and write out variable-named file from list of variables

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I would like to create multiple 'wget' shell scripts to download a batch of considerably large (~3GB) files using our HPC cluster. The names of the files are stored in filenames.txt, like so:

```
$cat filenames.txt
file1
file2
file3
...
```

and the urls I would like to wget from are structured like so:

```
ftp://host.com/dir1/dir2/file1/file1.sra
ftp://host.com/dir1/dir2/file2/file2.sra
ftp://host.com/dir1/dir2/file3/file3.sra
```

I'd like to create a shell script for each wget and write it out into a file named as the variable itself. For example, file1.sh should contain:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget ftp://host.com/dir1/dir2/file1/file1.sra
```

and file2.sh should contain:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget ftp://host.com/dir1/dir2/file2/file2.sra
```

As you can see, the pattern to match is 1) The URL and 2) the filename to be written out. How would I 'append' the URL to the filename, then write it out into a .sh file named after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a very simple shell loop to do this:

```
while read filename
do
    echo '#!/bin/bash' > $filename.sh
    echo "wget ftp://host.com/dir1/dir2/$filename/$filename.sra" >> $filename.sh
done < filenames.txt
```

This reads each line from `filenames.txt` and calls it `filename`, then for each one writes out a file named `$filename.sh`, where `$filename` is replaced with the line from the file. That file has two lines: `#!/bin/bash`, in every file, and then the `wget` command you wanted, again with the file name substituted in. `>>` is appending that second line into the same file, rather than overwriting. After running this script:

```
$ cat file1.sh 
#!/bin/bash
wget ftp://host.com/dir1/dir2/file1/file1.sra
$ cat file2.sh
#!/bin/bash
wget ftp://host.com/dir1/dir2/file2/file2.sra
```

---

You may want to add a third line inside the loop body:

```
chmod a+x "$filename.sh"
```

to make the scripts be executable afterwards. Put that immediately above the `done` line.

---

If any of your file names have spaces or other special characters in them then this will fall apart (on multiple levels), but for alphanumeric names it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
awk -v url='ftp://host.com/dir1/dir2' '{printf "#!/bin/bash\nwget %s/%s/%s.sra\n",url,$1,$1 >$1".sh"}' filenames.txt
```

After this command is run, there will be a series of files in the current directory like:

```
$ ls *.sh
file1.sh  file2.sh  file3.sh
```

The contents of each looks something like:

```
$ cat file1.sh
#!/bin/bash
wget ftp://host.com/dir1/dir2/file1/file1.sra
```

#### How it works

- `-v url='ftp://host.com/dir1/dir2'`

  This defines a `url` as an `awk` variable.
- `printf "#!/bin/bash\nwget %s/%s/%s.sra\n",url,$1,$1 >$1".sh"`

  This prints out each file that you need.  The `>$1".sh"` part means that each shell script is written to a file named after the file it downloads with a `.sh` extension added.

Comment: just thought I'd let you know I tried this and it worked too. And since I'm very new to awk, the explanations were helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another proposition, using `for` loop, `printf`, and command substitution `$()`:

```
for file in $(<filenames); do
    printf "%s\n%s\n" '#!/bin/bash' "wget ftp://host.com/dir1/dir2/${file}/${file}.sra" > "${file}.sh"
done
```

The only non-trival part is probably `$(<filename)`, what is equivalent of `$(cat filename)`, but a little bit faster.